# In IDA's strings window, how to run MakeStrLit on all the selection

Tags: ida, strings

Ida allows to turn bytes into a string using the A shortcut

[image]

There is also this window to find strings :

[image]

You can press enter to jump to a specific string, but is it possible to run MakeStrLit on all the selected strings ?

Answer (score 2):

You can try copy-pasting the following code into the built-in Python interpreter:

```
import idautils

for s in idautils.Strings():
    ida_bytes.create_strlit(s.ea, 0, ida_nalt.STRTYPE_TERMCHR)
```

This will create string literals for all the entries in the Strings window.